# Rails generate controller boilerplate for existing resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-generate

I used `generate scaffold` to setup the basic RESTful actions however I want to extend the actions to include something like 'purchase'. Is there a way to use the command line to generate the boilerplate (stub functions in controller file and updated route file?)?

As far as I can tell `generate controller` either wipes or leaves the existing file - there's no nice way to merge them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not by default. However, realize that in Rails 3, customizing generators isn't terribly difficult. See [Creating and Customizing Rails Generators & Templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html), and Bates' screencast on [Generators in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/216-generators-in-rails-3).

Regarding your second "question," that's right -- the file is either replaced or overwritten.